# How to reference Oracle linked server to specific database

Tags: visual-studio-2013, oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

I have a linked server on SQL Server 2008 R2 connecting to Oracle 11g. The linked server connects to a specific database, so querying it requires a 4-part name with the database *excluded* (`SELECT * FROM LinkedServer..Schema.Table`).

This syntax generates a build warning in SSDT:

> contains an unresolved reference to an object

I have tried:

1. adding the linked server to the same database project
2. creating a database project for `master` and adding it there under 'Server Objects' (this won't work because the target database uses other objects from `master` and, after importing from the `master` database or `.dacpac` file, I can't get the master project to build)
3. creating a shim database project for the linked server...but I don't have an easy way to generate SQL compatible `CREATE` scripts for the referenced objects

Is there any other way to get this to work in SSDT?

Comment: Hope [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/280106) helps.

Comment: Thanks, but not really. I've already setup the linked server. The problem is with SSDT.

Answer (score 0):

After you define the linked server in the database project, you can bypass the SSDT validation checks using the OPENQUERY function:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,
    'SELECT * FROM Schema.Table');
```

HTH

Comment: How would you accomplish the same thing for `INSERT`s?

Comment: Did you try a syntax like this one? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5d081d7e-a3e6-4ab6-9d05-44754f343735/inserting-data-into-another-table-using-openquery?forum=transactsql

Comment: No, I haven't. I didn't even realize that was possible.